# How to properly run a MForm defined in a subsite of a scaffolded Yesod site?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying a CRUD scenario with Yesod subsites with LTS 18.21 and can't figure out how to properly run the forms defined in the subsite. The following code compiles and works as expected, but I can't get rid of the `m~App` constraint. What should I change to get rid of the `m~App` constraint in the following definitions? Is it even right what I did? All examples seem to be outdated: HandlerT is deprecated and lift doesn't work as in examples.

```
-- config/models.persistentmodels
...
District sql=districts
  code Text
  name Text
  deriving Show
...
```

```
-- config/routes.yesodroutes
...
/dictionary/districts DictionaryDistrictsR GET
/dictionary/districts/crud DistrictSubR DistrictCrud getDistrictSub
...
```

```
-- src/Dictionary/District/Data.hs
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

module Dictionary.District.Data where

import Yesod
  ( mkYesodSubData
  , parseRoutes
  , RenderRoute (renderRoute, Route)
  , Yesod
  , RenderMessage
  , FormMessage
  , SubHandlerFor
  )
import Model (DistrictId)

data DistrictCrud = DistrictCrud

mkYesodSubData "DistrictCrud" [parseRoutes|
/new/district DistrictNewR GET POST
/edit/#DistrictId DistrictEditR GET POST
/delete/#DistrictId DistrictDeleteR GET POST
|]
  
class (Yesod m, RenderMessage m FormMessage) => YesodDistrict m where
  toParent :: Route m

type DistrictHandler m a = YesodDistrict m => SubHandlerFor DistrictCrud m a
```

```
-- src/Foundation.hs
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module Foundation where
...
instance YesodDistrict App where
  toParent = DictionaryDistrictsR

instance Yesod App where
...
```

```
-- src/Dictionary/District/DistrictSub.hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}

module Dictionary.District.DistrictSub
  ( module Dictionary.District.Data
  , module Dictionary.District.DistrictSub
  ) where
...
instance (YesodDistrict m, m ~ App) => YesodSubDispatch DistrictCrud m where
  yesodSubDispatch = $(mkYesodSubDispatch resourcesDistrictCrud)
...  
postDistrictNewR :: (YesodDistrict m, m ~ App)
  => DistrictHandler m Html
postDistrictNewR = liftHandler $ do
  ((r,w),e) <- runFormPost $ districtForm Nothing
  case r of
    FormSuccess x -> do
      _ <- runDB $ insert x
      redirect DictionaryDistrictsR
    _ -> do
      defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewDistrict}
  <form method=post enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    <div .d-flex.flex-column.gap-3>
      ^{w}
      <div .d-flex.flex-row.justify-content-start.aligh-items-center.gap-3>
        <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
          _{MsgSave}
        <a href=@{DictionaryDistrictsR} .btn.btn-primary role=button>
          _{MsgCancel}
  |]

getDistrictNewR :: (YesodDistrict m, m ~ App) => DistrictHandler m Html
getDistrictNewR = do
  -- mBack <- getCurrentRoute  
  -- backToParent <- (\x -> x DistrictNewR) <$> getRouteToParent
  liftHandler $ do
    (w,e) <- generateFormPost $ districtForm Nothing
    defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewDistrict}
  <form method=post enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    <div .d-flex.flex-column.gap-3>
      ^{w}
      <div .d-flex.flex-row.justify-content-start.aligh-items-center.gap-3>
        <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
          _{MsgSave}
        <a href=@{toParent} .btn.btn-primary role=button>
          _{MsgCancel}
        
  |]

districtForm :: (YesodDistrict m, m ~ App)
  => Maybe District -> Html -> MForm (HandlerFor m) (FormResult District, Widget)
districtForm mDistrict extra = do
  let classFor x = case fvErrors x of
                  Nothing -> "form-control"
                  _ -> "form-control is-invalid"
                  
  (_,codeV') <- mreq textField
    "Code"{fsName = Just "districtCode"} (districtCode <$> mDistrict)
  (codeR,codeV) <- mreqMsg textField
    "Code"{ fsName = Just "districtCode"
          , fsAttrs = [("class", classFor codeV')]
          } MsgValueIsRequired (districtCode <$> mDistrict)
    
  (_,nameV') <- mreq textField
    "Name"{fsName = Just "districtName"} (districtName <$> mDistrict)
  (nameR,nameV) <- mreqMsg textField
    "Name"{ fsName = Just "districtName"
          , fsAttrs = [("class", classFor nameV')]
          } MsgValueIsRequired (districtName <$> mDistrict)
  let r = District <$> codeR <*> nameR
  let w = do
        [whamlet|
                ^{extra}
                <div .d-flex.flex-column.gap-1>
                  <div .form-floating.mb-3>
                    ^{fvInput codeV}
                    <label for=#{fvId codeV}>_{MsgCode} *
                    $maybe errs <- fvErrors codeV
                      <div .invalid-feedback>
                        ^{errs}
                <div .d-flex.flex-column.gap-1>
                  <div .form-floating.mb-3>
                    ^{fvInput nameV}
                    <label for=#{fvId nameV}>_{MsgDenomination} *
                    $maybe errs <- fvErrors nameV
                      <div .invalid-feedback>
                        ^{errs}
        |]
    
  return (r,w)
```

Note that if I don't use the `m~App` constraint I get an error:

```
./src/Dictionary/District/DistrictSub.hs:75:24: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘App’
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at src/Dictionary/District/DistrictSub.hs:74:10-61
      Expected type: Yesod.Core.Types.YesodSubRunnerEnv DistrictCrud m
                     -> Network.Wai.Application
        Actual type: Yesod.Core.Types.YesodSubRunnerEnv DistrictCrud App
                     -> Network.Wai.Internal.Request
                     -> (Network.Wai.Internal.Response
                         -> IO Network.Wai.Internal.ResponseReceived)
                     -> IO Network.Wai.Internal.ResponseReceived
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add all necessary constraints for each handler function of the subsite:

```
-- src/Dictionary/District/Data.hs
...
data DistrictCrud = DistrictCrud
...
class (Yesod m, RenderMessage m FormMessage) => YesodDistrict m where
  toMaster :: m -> Route m
...
```

```
-- src/Foundation.hs
...
instance YesodDistrict App where
  toMaster _ = DictionaryDistrictsR
...
```

```
-- src/Dictionary/District/DistrictSub.hs
...
instance
  ( YesodDistrict m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => YesodSubDispatch DistrictCrud m where
  yesodSubDispatch = $(mkYesodSubDispatch resourcesDistrictCrud)
...
postDistrictNewR ::
  ( YesodDistrict m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => SubHandlerFor DistrictCrud m Html
postDistrictNewR = liftHandler $ do
  master <- getYesod
  ((r,w),e) <- runFormPost $ districtForm Nothing
  case r of
    FormSuccess x -> do
      _ <- runDB $ insert x
      redirect $ toMaster master
    _ -> do
      defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewDistrict}
  <form method=post enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    <div .d-flex.flex-column.gap-3>
      ^{w}
      <div .d-flex.flex-row.justify-content-start.aligh-items-center.gap-3>
        <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
          _{MsgSave}
        <a href=@{toMaster master} .btn.btn-primary role=button>
          _{MsgCancel}
  |]

getDistrictNewR ::
  ( YesodDistrict m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => SubHandlerFor DistrictCrud m Html
getDistrictNewR = liftHandler $ do
  master <- getYesod
  (w,e) <- generateFormPost $ districtForm Nothing
  defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewDistrict}
  <form method=post enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    <div .d-flex.flex-column.gap-3>
      ^{w}
      <div .d-flex.flex-row.justify-content-start.aligh-items-center.gap-3>
        <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
          _{MsgSave}
        <a href=@{toMaster master} .btn.btn-primary role=button>
          _{MsgCancel}
        
  |]

districtForm :: (YesodDistrict m, RenderMessage m AppMessage, RenderMessage m FormMessage)
  => Maybe District -> Html -> MForm (HandlerFor m) (FormResult District, WidgetFor m ())
districtForm mDistrict extra = do
....
```